# MathJax and Android's Chrome bug

Tags: bug, mathjax

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovxSE.jpg) is what I see on Chrome 35.0.1916.122, Android 4.4.2 (KitKat), Nexus 5:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm the problem, and it does not go away on page refresh. The layout is fine before Mathjax renders, but when the original text LaTeX is replaced by rendered LaTeX, it seems not enough space is left for the rendered text.

Comment: The problem appears to be that MathJax hasn't been able to measure the size of the surrounding font properly.  There are two reasons this might occur.  First, it could be that a web-font is used for the text font (I haven't checked what the mobile version does), and the font isn't in place when MathJax takes its measurements, so it is measuring the default font instead.  Second, some mobile browsers change the scaling factor after the page is loaded, and that might also throw off MathJax.

Comment: Try entering `javascript:MathJax.Hub.Rerender()` in the URL bar and see if that causes the proper amount of space to be reserved.

Comment: @Davide Cervone: that does not appear to solve the problem with my Android phone running the same version of Chrome as in the question.

Comment: @CarlMummert, OK, thanks for trying.  I'll have to look harder to figure it out.  I don't have an Android 4.4 device, and my phone at 4.1 doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: FWIW I cannot reproduce this on a Moto G, same Android and Chrome version. @CarlMummert does the rerendering not work or not make a difference?

Comment: @Peter: I have now updated to Chrome 35.0.1916.138, and I have the same problem. I think I was not running the re-render correctly. Now if I do it (and put a semicolon after the command in the address bar) then I can see it re-render, and the spacing is fixed after that. But the first rendering still has the spacing problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Carl. That confirms Davide's suspicion.

Comment: I see the same problem on Chrome 35.0.1916.141 but using `javascript:MathJax.Hub.Defender();` does not fix the rendering for me: it rerenders with overlaps again.